# use @jsonProerty annotation instead of getter method while mapping json string to object

Tags: json, jackson

Java Class

```
public class Employee{

    @JsonProperty("NAME")
    private String name;
   

 @JsonProperty("NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("NAME")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

  }
```

Input Json String {"NAME":"xxxx"}

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
 
 Employee employee = mapper.readValue(jsonMessage, Employee.class);
```

system.out.println(employee.toString);

output === {"name":"xxxx"}

while mappring json string to java class, Is there any way to tell to use @JsonProperty instead of getterMethod ?
if I print object, expecting same output as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused `System.out.println` which does not obey any Jackson annotation with a classical `String employeeAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(employee)`.

Try the latter one and you'll get your field name in uppercase.